# How do I make a radial menu?

Tags: html, css, button, css-shapes

[Button Panel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MtvXe9Gsg2TFZxNjB6TEZxTUU/view?usp=sharing)

How to create this **Button Panel** in **Above Link** using **HTML** & **CSS**?
(White shapes are buttons)

[image]

Comment: I think it might be better to create `label` elements, and hide the buttons themselves. That way you can have multiple elements building up into a single clickable area, and use a more flexible approach via [CSS transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). Long story short, what you are asking for is entirely possible, but involves some thinking and experimenting. IMO this isn't something that can be answered, strictly speaking.

Comment: Don't link to google drive files that are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You could try positioning them. However, this only really works if you know how many links you're going to use. Otherwise, a javascript approach would be more beneficial if you're using a dynamic/unknown number of links

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:10px solid black;
  }
div:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:70%;
  width:70%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:black;
  top:15%;
  left:15%;
  z-index:8;
  }
div a {
  position:absolute;
  padding:20px;
  background:tomato;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  }
div a:nth-child(1){
  bottom:-10%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  }
div a:nth-child(2){
  bottom:10%;
  left:10%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) rotate(55deg);
  }
div a:nth-child(3){
  bottom:10%;
  left:90%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) rotate(-55deg);
  }

div a:hover{
  background:cornflowerblue;
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Lnk</a>
  <a href="#">Lnk</a>
  <a href="#">Lnk</a>
</div>
```

**Note**

you could also try using perspective, although I think js would be a much better option here

- [SCSS solution](http://codepen.io/joexadrez/pen/cDgfo)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this site which contains several styled buttons only using `border-radius` [Sweet CSS3 Buttons](http://simurai.com/archive/buttons/)

However what you are trying to do, if you choose to to it using buttons/divs *(instead of canvas or SVG)* you whil need also to use css `transform` whit `rotate` and `translateY` / `translateX`. 
Probably something like this:

```
// Clockwise 
.button2 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(100px) translateX(-100px);
}
.button3 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(100px) translateX(-100px);
}
.button4 {
    transform: rotate(135deg) translateY(-100px) translateX(100px);
}
.button5 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(100px) translateX(-100px);
}
```

I hope this helps.
Regards